# How to corrupt a SQL Server page for test purpose?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I'd like to corrupt a page of any table from [AdventureWorks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms) Database. How to do it?

I'd like to test page level restore and, also, bring a suspect database online again using dbcc checkdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dbcc writepage](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/dbcc-writepage/)

Disclaimer !!

> DBCC WRITEPAGE – the most dangerous command you can use in SQL Server.